# Handle html element click function in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a function which handles a click function for an element:

```
proot.find("li.ls-child-true").children('div').click(function (e) {
});
```

My problem is I would like to handle click function on a div child element.

The div looks like this:

```
<div><a>not clickable</a><a>clickable</a></div>
```

So, I would like to handle the second anchor click function only, I tried to use this code, but it's not working:

```
proot.find("li.ls-child-true").children('div').children('a')[1].click(function (e) {
});
```

Can anybody help to me? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)/[`:eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) instead of `[1]`, Note `[]` will return reference to DOM element which don't have access to jQuery methods

```
proot.find("li.ls-child-true").children('div').children('a').eq(1).click(function (e) {
});
```

You can improve your selectors

```
proot.find("li.ls-child-true > div >a:eq(1)").click(function (e) {
});
```